# Multi-slice pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']})
```

that I would like to slice into two new dataframes such that the first contains every *nth* value, while the second contains the remaining values not in the first.

For example, in the case of *n=3*, the second dataframe would keep two values from the original dataframe, skip one, keep two, skip one, etc. This slice is illustrated in the following image where the original dataframe values are blue, and these are split into a green set and a red set:

[image]

I have achieved this successfully using a combination of `iloc` and `isin`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[::3]
df2 = df[~df.val.isin(df1.val)]
```

but what I would like to know is:

Is this the most Pythonic way to achieve this? It seems inefficient and not particularly elegant to take what I want out of a dataframe then get the rest of what I want by checking what is not in the new dataframe that is in the original. Instead, is there an `iloc` expression, like that which was used to generate `df1`, which could do the second part of the slicing procedure and replace the `isin` line? Even better, is there a single expression that could execute the the entire two-step slice in one step?

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo `3` with compare for not equal first values (same like sliced rows):

```
#for default RangeIndex
df2 = df[df.index % 3 != 0]
#for any Index
df2 = df[np.arange(len(df)) %  3 != 0]
print (df2)
  val
1   b
2   c
4   e
5   f
7   h
```